# Struts2 TreeView table drag and drop

Tags: jsp, struts2, treeview

I have JSP page that presents a table treeview for folders. These folders are JSON `<s:iterator ... >`
Folders contain plan.pdf which are also `<s:iterator`

**Example**:

```
Root
Folder1
 plan1.pdf
 plan2.pdf
subFolder1.1
 plan1.pdf
subFolder1.2
 plan1.pdf
Folder2
 plan1.pdf
```

Now I drag Folder1.2 and paste to Folder1.1 .. the treeview will become:

```
 - Root
 - Folder1
 -  plan1.pdf
 -  plan2.pdf
 - subFolder1.1
 -  plan1.pdf
 - subsubFolder1.1.2
 -  plan1.pdf
```

Any suggestion?

Also do you have any idea how to show treeview as this

```
- Root
 - |--- Folder 1
 - |  |--- subFolder 1.1
 - |  |--- subFolder 1.2
 - |--- Folder 2
 - |  |--- subFolder 2.1
 - |--- Folder 3
 - |  |--- subFolder 3.1
```

Code:

Class PlanFolder

```
@Entity
@Table(name="plan_folder")
public class PlanFolder extends EntiteSynchroniseeAbstract implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="plan_folder_id")
private int planFolderId;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Projet
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="project_id")
private Projet projet;

//bi-directional One To One association to PlanFolder
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable=true, name="root_id")
private PlanFolder root;

@Column(name="plan_folder_name")
private String planFolderName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Plan
@OneToMany(mappedBy="folder")
private List<Plan> plans;

//setters and getters
```

DAO Interface

```
public interface DaoPlanFolder extends Dao<PlanFolder> {

public List<PlanFolder> getPlanFolders(int projetId);
public void deleteFolder(int planfolderId);
public PlanFolder getRacine (int projetId);

public List<PlanFolder> verifiePlanFolder (int projetId, int planId, String planFolderName);

public void  moveFolder (int planfolderId , int newRootId );
public void renameFolder (int planfolderId , String newName);
public PlanFolder createFolder(String name, int projetId, int rootId , int planId);
public Fichier telechargeMiniature(int projetId);
public List<Plan> getPlans(int projetId, int folderId);
public Fichier chargerFichierCompressed(Fichier archive , int projetId, Utilisateur utilisateur, File source);
public void deleteByIdPlanFolder (int planFolderId)  ;
public PlanFolder createRacine(String name, int projetId);
}
```

Action

```
    public String movePlanFolder() {
    DaoPlanFolder daoPlanFolder = DaoFactory.getDaoPlanFolder();    
    daoPlanFolder.moveFolder(this.planFolderId, this.rootId);
    daoPlanFolder.close();
    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**JSP**

```
 <s:if test="planFolders.size > 0">
    <table id="table_planFolders" class="table_datas">
        <tr>

            <th class="largeur_5"></th>
            <th class="largeur_5"></th>
            <th class="largeur_25"></th>                            
            <th class="largeur_25"></th>

            <th><s:text name="plans.th.nom"/></th>
            <th class="largeur_100"><s:text name="plans.th.indice"/></th>
            <th class="largeur_100"><s:text name="plans.th.echelle"/></th>
            <th class="largeur_160"></th>

                    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                <div class="separateur"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <s:iterator value="planFolders" status="status">
            <tr id="${planFolderId}" class="${status.even ? 'tr_paire' : ''}">

                <td onclick="<s:set var="rootId" value="rootId"/>">

                    <s:if test="rootId != 0">   
                    <ul>
                        <li>  
                            <c:set var="plus" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/elements/plus.png" scope="request"/>
                            <s:submit type="image" src="%{#request.plus}"  onclick="createPlanFolder('%{planFolderName}','%{planFolderId}',0)"/>
                         </li>      

                        <li>  
                            <c:set var="main" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/elements/main.png" scope="request"/>
                            <s:submit type="image" src="%{#request.main}" onclick="deplacePlanFolder('%{planFolderId}','%{rootId}')"/>
                         </li>      
                    </ul>
                            </s:if></td>
                <td>
                    <table><tr><td>
                            <s:if test="rootId != 0">
                                <s:if test="'%{planFolders[counter].rootId}'!='%{racineId}'">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(traitdebase);</script>
                                </s:if>                                     
                            </s:if></td>    <td>
                            <input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/elements/repertoire.png" height="42" width="42">
                    </td></tr></table>
                </td>

                <td>            
                    <h2>${planFolderName}</h2>
                </td>
                <td>        </td>

                <td>        </td>
                <td>    </td>
                <td>    </td>

                <td>
                    <s:if test="rootId != 0">
                        <ul>                                
                        <li class="lien" onclick="renamePlanFolder(${planFolderId})"><s:text name="planFolder.lien.RenameFolder"/></li>
                            <li class="lien" onclick="deletePlanFolder(${planFolderId})"><s:text name="planFolder.lien.DeleteFolder"/></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </s:if>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>        
                <s:if test="plans.size > 0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8">
                            <div class="separateur"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <s:iterator value="plans" status="status">
                        <tr class="${status.even ? 'tr_paire' : ''}">           

                            <td>                        
                                <ul>
                                    <li>  

                                        <c:set var="plus" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/elements/plus.png" scope="request"/>
                                        <s:submit type="image" src="%{#request.plus}"  onclick="createPlanFolder('%{planNom}','%{planFolderId}','%{planId}')"/>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>  
                                        <c:set var="main" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/elements/main.png" scope="request"/>
                                        <s:submit type="image" src="%{#request.main}" />
                                    </li>           
                                </ul>   
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <s:if test="'%{planFolders[counter].rootId}'!='%{racineId}'">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(traitdeplan);</script>
                                </s:if>
                            </td>                                               

                            <td></td>   
                            <td>
                                <s:if test="indiceActuel.indiceStatut == 2">
                                    <img class="pointeur" src="TelechargeMiniature.bp?indiceId=${indiceActuel.indiceId}" align="middle" onclick="affichePlan(${planId})" />
                                </s:if>
                                <s:elseif test="indiceActuel.indiceStatut == 3">
                                    <s:text name="plans.message.error"/>
                                </s:elseif>
                                <s:else>
                                    <s:text name="plans.message.enCours"/>
                                </s:else>
                            </td>
                            <td><b>${planNom}</b></td>
                            <td>${indiceActuel.indiceNumero}</td>
                            <td><s:text name="enum.echelle.%{indiceActuel.echelleEnum}" /></td>

                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="lien" onclick="augmenterIndice(${planId})" ><s:text name="plans.lien.nouvelIndice"/></li>
                                    <li class="lien" onclick="modifierPlan(${planId})"><s:text name="plans.lien.modifierPlan"/></li>
                                    <li class="lien" onclick="supprimerIndice(${planId})"><s:text name="plans.lien.supprimerIndice"/></li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>       
                    </s:iterator>
                </s:if>
            </tr ><script type="text/javascript">counter = counter+1;</script>
        </s:iterator>       



    </table>
</s:if>
```

Our client had a scenario in mind I put it as images - he wants by clicking on the hand the hand turn into orange and that means this is the folder which I want to move [selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrn26.png).

After that by clicking on another folder which becomes blue selection that means this new root (destination) [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipr4N.png).

I want to do it more complicated as a drag and drop rows.

Comment: Code. Show your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: it's my first time here .. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks @halfer  ... my post is more clarified